# Can not add product to cart rest API

Tags: magento2

I Have this problem when trying to add a product to cart:

```
{"message":"No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue","parameters":{"fieldName":"cartId","fieldValue":null}}
```

My API:

`POST` on:

```
https://domain.com/rest/V1/guest-carts/ce7b9f063fb07fcb03d71a2eff922d8d/items?cartItem[sku]=1508110&cartItem[qty]=1&cartItem[quote_id]=353
```

- `ce7b9f063fb07fcb03d71a2eff922d8d` is the cart-key which I got through API:

  POST http://domain.com/rest/V1/guest-carts
- `quote_id = 353` is the id which I got from cart details through API:

  GET `http://domain.com/rest/V1/guest-carts/ce7b9f063fb07fcb03d71a2eff922d8d`

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can refer to the offical swagger documentation : http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_20.html#/

**1/** You need to create a guest cart :

```
POST http://domain.com/rest/V1/guest-carts
```

Which return a guest cart id such as `881d962b14c14764a0f5939be4722cbc`.

**2/** **(Optional)** Retrieve the quote id from this API call :

```
GET http://domain.com/rest/V1/guest-carts/881d962b14c14764a0f5939be4722cbc
```

Where a field id correspond to the quote id, for example `"id": 31`.

**3/** Add a product to your cart :

```
POST http://domain.com/rest/V1/guest-carts/881d962b14c14764a0f5939be4722cbc/items
```

The payload pattern is :

```
{
  "cartItem": {
    "itemId": 0,
    "sku": "string",
    "qty": 0,
    "name": "string",
    "price": 0,
    "productType": "string",
    "quoteId": "881d962b14c14764a0f5939be4722cbc",
    "productOption": {
      "extensionAttributes": {
        "customOptions": [
          {
            "optionId": "string",
            "optionValue": "string",
            "extensionAttributes": {
              "fileInfo": {
                "base64EncodedData": "string",
                "type": "string",
                "name": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "downloadableOption": {
          "downloadableLinks": [
            0
          ]
        },
        "giftcardItemOption": {
          "giftcardAmount": 0,
          "customGiftcardAmount": 0,
          "giftcardSenderName": "string",
          "giftcardRecipientName": "string",
          "giftcardSenderEmail": "string",
          "giftcardRecipientEmail": "string",
          "giftcardMessage": "string",
          "extensionAttributes": {}
        },
        "configurableItemOptions": [
          {
            "optionId": "string",
            "optionValue": 0,
            "extensionAttributes": {}
          }
        ],
        "bundleOptions": [
          {
            "optionId": 0,
            "optionQty": 0,
            "optionSelections": [
              0
            ],
            "extensionAttributes": {}
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "extensionAttributes": {}
  }
}
```

An example for a basic configurable product :

```
{
  "cartItem": {
    "sku": "ProductSKU",
    "qty": 1,
    "quoteId": "881d962b14c14764a0f5939be4722cbc",
    "productOption": {
      "extensionAttributes": {
        "configurableItemOptions": [
          {
            "optionId": "178",
            "optionValue": 45,
            "extensionAttributes": {}
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Magento uses both cartId and quoteId that referece on different internal id.

Comment: you can use postman as an alternative or soap ui for a more robust software.

Comment: In HTTP requester addon, set the POST payload in the content form with application/json content type

Comment: Still got the same error

Comment: I just updated my answer, use the long cartId for the POST payload : for example 881d962b14c14764a0f5939be4722cbc . Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @FranckGarnier How can I get the optionId and optionValue as a guest user?

Comment: @N. Karthic Kannan I do not understand your question, sorry.

Comment: Thank you - my issue was that I assumed quoteID was the actual entity_id of the quote (e.g. 31 in your example above) vs the generated cartID